# Legal Baltimore Knives

Tags: self-defense, weapons, maryland

I recently moved to the Downtown Baltimore, Maryland area and as you may know it's an extremely high crime area that has a lot of homicides. As a result I've been trying to find ways I can defend myself. I've been walking around with pepper spray but I'm curious if I can legally walk around with a concealed knife. I spent a lot of time reading the various laws around knives in Baltimore and Maryland but it's a little hard making sense of which knives are actually legal. I understand that pretty much any folding knife that doesn't mechanically open is legal but it's the pen knife that is hard for me to determine whether or not it's legal. Below is an example knife I have that does not fold but is rather kept inside a sheath. I'm wondering if I can conceal carry this knife legally.

[image]

[image]